# Qt Designer - change tab index with button

Tags: python, qt, tabs, designer

i have a problem with QT Designer. I want to focus on specific tab in tabWidget with a button. You know.. i click one the for example button1 and tabs change. Anyone know how to do it? I also tryed ,after converting the ui file to .py, to do this in code but didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setCurrentIndex` :

If you have a button you can connect the clicked signal to a function and call `setCurrentIndex` of `tabwidget` :

```
self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Change Tab', self)
self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

def handleButton(self):
    tabwidget.setCurrentIndex(neededIndex)
```